# How to pass in variable in the hover label using plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

```
mydat2 <- data.frame(subject = c("math", "english", "chemistry"), score = c(80, 50, 65), class = c("A", "B", "A"), count = c(50, 60, 70))
> mydat2
    subject score class count
1      math    80     A    50
2   english    50     B    60
3 chemistry    65     A    70
```

I have the above data. And I plot the following:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = mydat2,
        x = ~score,
        y = ~count,
        color = ~class,
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~subject,
        hovertemplate = paste(
          "<b>%{text}</b><br><br>",
          "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:,.0f}<br>",
          "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:,.0f}<br>",
          "Class: %{color:,.0f}",
          "<extra></extra>"
        ))
```

I want the hover label to also include what the `class` is. However, I cannot seem to get the right hover label. It's showing up as `Class: %{color:.,.0f}`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to use the "customdata" option in the hover text definition.

```
mydat2 <- data.frame(subject = c("math", "english", "chemistry"), score = c(80, 50, 65), class = c("A", "B", "A"), count = c(50, 60, 70))

library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = mydat2,
        x = ~score,
        y = ~count,
        color = ~class,
        customdata= ~class,
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~subject,
        hovertemplate = paste(
           "<b>%{text}</b><br><br>",
           "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:,.0f}<br>",
           "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:,.0f}<br>",
           "Class: %{customdata}",
           "<extra></extra>"
        ))
```

Comment: Using the code you provided, do you know why the `subject` for the left most point (i.e. the one that corresponds to `english    50     B    60`) is showing up as `%{text}` instead of `english`?

Comment: Adrian, sorry, this is one of those quirks with plotly that I can't figure out.  Your follow-up question here seems to nail it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840856/why-is-hovertemplate-not-showing-up-correctly-for-some-data-points-for-plotly-in