# Why is hovertemplate not showing up correctly for some data points for plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

```
mydat2 <- data.frame(subject = c("math", "english", "chemistry"), score = c(80, 50, 65), class = c("A", "B", "A"), count = c(50, 60, 70))

library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = mydat2,
        x = ~score,
        y = ~count,
        color = ~class,
        customdata= ~class,
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~subject,
        hovertemplate = paste(
           "<b>%{text}</b><br><br>",
           "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:,.0f}<br>",
           "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:,.0f}<br>",
           "Class: %{customdata}",
           "<extra></extra>"
        ))
```

[image]

I'm confused as to why the hover for the left most point shows up as `%{text}` instead of `english`. The hover labels for the other 2 points on the plot are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your graph, with the hover template that you're looking for. The explanation follows.

```
plot_ly(data = mydat2,
        x = ~score,
        y = ~count,
        color = ~class,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers",
        customdata= ~class,
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~I(subject),         # <---- I changed!!
        hovertemplate = paste(
          "<b>%{text}</b><br><br>",
          "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:,.0f}<br>",
          "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:,.0f}<br>",
          "Class: %{customdata}",
          "<extra></extra>"
        ))
```

[image]

I've seen this problem before. I've usually come up with a workaround, but never really figured out what went wrong until now. I found a closed ticket on GitHub for this issue (closed in 2019). (Ah, ya... so not fixed.) Apparently, it has to do with using color.

However, the bright spot...for a hot minute someone actually believed it was a problem and came up with a fix. @cpsievert wrote a bit of code that includes an `lapply` call (towards the middle of the page, if you visit the site). When I investigated what the code did, I realized it could be a lot simpler (and it was pretty simple, to begin with).

That ticket on GitHub is [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/864) if you wanted to check that out.

This is the code the maintainer provided (that you don't actually need).

```
l <- plotly_build(p)$x
l$data <- lapply(l$data, function(tr) { tr[["text"]] <- I(tr[["text"]]); tr })
as_widget(l)
```

The fix is the function `I()`. Instead of `hovertext =`  or `text = ~subject`, you need `hovertext =`  or `text = ~I(subject)`. <-- note the `I()`